# Google API throwing Rate Limit Exceeded 403 exception for CDN cache invalidation

Tags: java, google-api, aem

We are caching our pages and content in Google CDN.

Google has provided us an API to invalidate cache for a particular page/path.

Our website is built using a CMS called AEM(Adobe Experience Manager), this CMS supports constant page/content updation eg. we may update what is shown on our https://our-webpage/homepage.html twice in a day. When such an operation is done there is a need to flush the cache at the Google CDN for **"homepage.html"**.

Such kind of an activity is very common, meaning **we need to send several cache invalidation requests(thousands) in a day.**

We are sending so many invalidation requests that after sometime we get this error

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Rate Limit Exceeded"
}
```

How do we solve this?

I've read this page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors

It mentions batching requests.

How do I send invalidation requests for multiple pages to Google CDN in one batch?

Or Is it possible to increase or set the API flush call limit to a higher number per day.

Right now if we have 100 pages to flush from CDN we make the below HTTP call 100 times(one for each page).

```
    CacheInvalidationRule requestBody = new CacheInvalidationRule();

        // IMPORTANT 
        requestBody.setPath(pagePath);

        Compute computeService = createComputeService();
        Compute.UrlMaps.InvalidateCache request =
                computeService.urlMaps().invalidateCache(projectName, urlMap, requestBody);
        Operation response = request.execute();

        if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Google CDN Flush Response JSON :: {}",response);
        }
    LOG.info("Google CDN Flush Invalidation for Page Path {}:: Response Status Code:: {}",pagePath,response.getStatus());
```

We set the page to flush in `requestBody.setPath(pagePath);`

Can we do this in a more efficient way, like sending all pages as an array or strings in one HTTP call?

Like :

requestBody.setPath(pagePath);

Where

```
pagePath="['/homepage.html','/videos.html','/sports/basketball.html','/tickets.html','/faqs.html']";
```

Answer (score 1):

`Rate Limit Exceeded` is flood protection you are going to fast slow down your requests.

> Implement exponential back off for retrying the requests.
>
> You can periodically retry a failed request over an increasing amount of time to handle errors related to rate limits, network volume, or response time. For example, you might retry a failed request after one second, then after two seconds, and then after four seconds. This method is called exponential backoff and it is used to improve bandwidth usage and maximize throughput of requests in concurrent environments. When using exponential backoff, consider the following:
>
> - Start retry periods at least one second after the error.
> - If the attempted request introduces a change, such as a create request, add a check to make sure nothing is duplicated. Some errors, such as invalid authorization credentials or "file not found" errors, aren’t resolved by retrying the request.

Batching wont help much your still going to be limited to the same issues with the rate limit i have even seen rate limit errors when batching.

Kindly note your link is from the Google drive api im not even sure Cloud CDN supports batching of requests.

Comment: Kindly note your link is from the Google drive api im not even sure Cloud CDN supports batching of requests. <--- Exactly  @DalmTo

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to aggregate several updates on AEM side and send only one request to the CDN after a max period of time and / or a max amount of changes?
I mean, if you change your homepage on AEM, usually you would invalidate all the subpages as well (navigation might change, ...).

Isn't there a possibility for the google cdn to invalidate a tree or subtree?
At least that's what I would extract from this documentation https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/url-maps/invalidate-cdn-cache